# Change the anchor points of an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to change the starting and ending positions of the arrow on the ellipses ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,bending]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\newcommand{\MyEllipse}[3]
   {(#1) ellipse [x radius=#2,y radius=#3]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   [arr/.style={->,shorten >= 8pt,shorten <= 8pt,thick},>=stealth]

\draw [fill=orange] \MyEllipse{0,0}{0.75}{0.5} node (e1) {$y_1$}; 

\draw [fill=orange] \MyEllipse{3,0}{0.75}{0.5} node (e2) {$y_2$}; 

\draw [fill=orange] \MyEllipse{6,0}{0.75}{0.5} node (e3) {$y_3$};

\draw[arr] (e1) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+t_1)$} (e2);
\draw[arr] (e2) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+t_2)$} (e3);
\draw[arr] (e1) to [bend left=-90] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+T)$}  (e3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you mean with anchor points? Arrow as as end of line hasn't anchors (as far as I understand TikZ)

Comment: @ Zarko I modified my question is this clearer ?

Comment: Now is clear, and you already receive adequate answer from @GonzaloMedina ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With your current approach you `\draw` the ellipses and then use `\node`s to place the labels inside. This will produce problems if you want to fine tune the starting and ending points of the arrows, since the anchors for the nodes will be used and those won't necessarily match the border of the ellipses.

If you want finer control on the arrows, I'd suggest you to use elliptical `\node`s; in this way, you have access to the node anchors to place the arrows starting and ending points at the desired locations; a little comparative example in which I used the `south` anchor and some angular anchors:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,bending]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}

\newcommand{\MyEllipse}[3]
   {(#1) ellipse [x radius=#2,y radius=#3]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  arr/.style={->,thick},
  >=stealth,
  mynode/.style={
    fill=orange,
    ellipse,
    draw,
    text width=0.75cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
    align=center
  }
]

\node[mynode] (e1) {$y_1$}; 
\node[mynode,right=of e1] (e2) {$y_2$}; 
\node[mynode,right=of e2] (e3) {$y_3$}; 

\draw[arr] 
  (e1) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+t_1)$} (e2);
\draw[arr] 
  (e2) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+t_2)$} (e3);
\draw[arr] 
  (e1) to [bend left=-90] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+T)$}  (e3);

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\node[mynode] (e1) {$y_1$}; 
\node[mynode,right=of e1] (e2) {$y_2$}; 
\node[mynode,right=of e2] (e3) {$y_3$}; 

\draw[arr] 
  (e1.south) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.6cm] {$\times(1+t_1)$} (e2.south);
\draw[arr] 
  (e2.south) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.6cm] {$\times(1+t_2)$} (e3.south);
\draw[arr] 
  (e1.south) to [bend left=-90] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+T)$}  (e3.south);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-4cm]
\node[mynode] (e1) {$y_1$}; 
\node[mynode,right=of e1] (e2) {$y_2$}; 
\node[mynode,right=of e2] (e3) {$y_3$}; 

\draw[arr] 
  (e1.340) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.6cm] {$\times(1+t_1)$} (e2.200);
\draw[arr] 
  (e2.340) to [bend left=-50] node [above=-0.6cm] {$\times(1+t_2)$} (e3.200);
\draw[arr] 
  (e1.220) to [bend left=-90] node [above=-0.75cm] {$\times(1+T)$}  (e3.320);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation, I learn a lot !